# Vim - how to substitute a word in-place?

Tags: vim, gvim

I would like to substitute a word in-place. For example, after yanking some word by pressing <kbd>yw</kbd> and then setting a cursor on some other word, I would like to press something so that substitution will happen. (e.g. <kbd>SOME_KEYw</kbd> where w is really w and SOME_KEY is some key). I would *not* like to switch into Insert Mode.

I am not interested in the `:%s/oldword/newword/gc` solution. I need interactive in-place substitution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is described in [Vim Tip 605](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text).

If you yank the first word with <kbd>yiw</kbd>, you can then replace another word with the first one by typing <kbd>viwp</kbd>.

If you leave out the <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>yw</kbd> will also yank the whitespace after your word and when pasting this you get too much spaces. Therefore, use <kbd>i</kbd> to select the **i**nner word.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it is counterintuitive; instead of "viwp" different typos happen like "iwvp", "wivp", ...

Very bad...

Comment: So maybe you shouldn't be using vim in the first place? Because typos might happen?

Comment: I am with vim since many years. A solution presented by Rene is better because it doesn't require typing "yiw" but only usual "yw"="Yank Word". But of course his solution is also bad because it requires key pressing 2+5 times to make only one substitution. Your solution requires pressing 3+4 times.

Comment: If you want "intuitive", you're using the wrong text editor.

Comment: I think that this is quite intuitive. First, yank the inner word, then visually select the inner word and paste. That's exactly what you would do with some visual editor using the mouse.

Comment: @psihodelia If you don't find this answer comfortable, you may not be familiar with vim's [text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select), like `ci(` and `da"`.  Those motions have been a huge help to me, and I recommend you try using them more often if you haven't already learned since asking this question.

Comment: `ye`, `vep` does the same and it's 2 keypresses shorter (my answer below).

Comment: @LawrenceVelázquez If you want intuitive, you're using the wrong <insert-any-human-invention>. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want cw<CTRL-R>0

This is to be typed as <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>ctrl+r</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: thanks but it is very uncomfortable and it switches edition mode to -Insert-

Comment: then create a map

Comment: What does `CTRL+R, 0` do?

Comment: The letter typed after CTRL+R is the name of the register whose content is to be filled in. See :help i_CTRL-R

Comment: should probably be added that he should be standing at the first letter of the word ...

Answer (score 1):

Building upon innaM's answer, with shorter input:

First copy the first word with <kbd>ye</kbd>.

Then replace any other word with this previously copied word with <kbd>vep</kbd>.

The `e` motion moves forward to the end of word [count] inclusive. Does not stop in an empty line.

Comment: What does `e` do?

Comment: @jpaugh `:help` tells what each command does, so `:help e` tells what `e` does:  **Forward to the end of word [count] inclusive. Does not stop in an empty line.**

Comment: Thanks. I'm away from vim atm, but it's good to have a complete answer.